# Rails Send Mail In Thread Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to send an email in a separate thread (for budget reason I don't want resque etc at the moment) . 
The email is sent when I call the mail function without a thread , but when I wrap it in a thread there is no email sent .

```
#Thread.new do
    puts "hello1"
    mail(to: "myemail@etc.etc", subject: "blah blah",body: some_var.text)
    puts "hello2"
 # end
```

So this piece of code works , but when I uncomment it the email isn't sent (I do however see "hello1 hello2" printed and I can step into the mail function , so the thread is calling the function and it finishes , but alas no mail is being sent).

I'm on Rails 4.16 , development mode (Webrick running from Rubymine) .

Answer (score 0):

If it's within mailer model like

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def my_method
    mail # ...
  end
end
```

Then it doesn't send the email, because you also need to call `.deliver` on it, so when you run it within a Thread, you don't return the `mail` object but `thread` - the main issue. It could probably run when you would have something like:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def my_method
    Thread.new do
      mail().deliver # parameters to mail method as needed 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the solution privied by @leszek-zalewski, but it was not working for me.

What I did is from the model (where I was triggering the email action) I changed it:

Before (in my NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base):

```
  def login_email()

    subject = 'New Login'

    Thread.new do 
      mail(to: "XYZ", subject: subject).deliver
    end
  end
```

Now (in the admin model):

```
  def after_database_authentication
    Thread.new do
      NotificationMailer.login_email().deliver
    end
  end
```

and I deleted the Thread.new block in the NotificationMailer

and there you go!

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveJob(stock in rails 4.2, and activejob_backport for rails 4+) with SuckerPunch backend to perform jobs in same process